# android convert a json object

Tags: android, json

In my android app, I am creating a function to convert to json object.
this is the code

```
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();

for (Modificateurs mod : this.getModificateurs()) {

    JSONObject pnObj = new JSONObject();

    pnObj.put(Artifact.JSON_MODIFICATEUR, mod.getModificateur());

    pnObj.put(Artifact.JSON_DATEMODIFICATION, mod.getDateModification());

    jsonArr.put(pnObj);

}

object.putOpt(Artifact.JSON_MODIFICATEURS, jsonArr);
```

Now i create this function to convert this json object but it still not working.

```
JSONArray jsonArr = object.getJSONArray(Artifact.JSON_MODIFICATEURS);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject objet = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    String modificateur = objet.optString(Artifact.JSON_MODIFICATEUR);
    String date = objet.optString(Artifact.JSON_DATEMODIFICATION);
    Modificateurs mod = new Modificateurs(modificateur, date);
    mods.add(mod);

}
this.modificateurs=mods;
```

What's wrong in my function?

Comment: What problem u are getting?

Comment: Can you please share your complete code which contains this conversion method etc?

Comment: i cannot see modifier, and when i want to show that in Log the app crashs in this line        { for (Modificateurs mod : this.getModificateurs()) }

Comment: If it crashes please post logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the comments, if your application crashes at line

```
for (Modificateurs mod : this.getModificateurs()) {
```

I guess it's a `NullPointerException` and `this.getModificateurs()` is returning `null`.
You have to check the nullity before iterating :

```
if (this.getModificateurs() != null) {
    for (Modificateurs mod : this.getModificateurs()) {
    ...
```